# Docker: Error code 127 when executing shell script

Tags: docker, shell, docker-compose, dockerfile

So I can't seem to figure this out, but I'm getting error code 127 when running a Dockerfile. What causes this error?

My **Dockerfile**:

```
FROM composer as comp

FROM php:7.4-fpm-alpine
COPY --from=comp /usr/bin/composer /usr/bin/composer
COPY ./docker/install-deps.sh /tmp/install-deps.sh
RUN echo $(ls /tmp)
RUN /tmp/install-deps.sh
COPY . /var/www
WORKDIR /var/www
RUN composer install -o --no-dev
```

The results after building the Dockerfile:

```
Building php
Step 1/9 : FROM composer as comp
 ---> 433420023b60
Step 2/9 : FROM php:7.4-fpm-alpine
 ---> 78e945602ecc
Step 3/9 : COPY --from=comp /usr/bin/composer /usr/bin/composer
 ---> 46117e22b4de
Step 4/9 : COPY ./docker/install-deps.sh /tmp/install-deps.sh
 ---> 7e46a2ee759c
Step 5/9 : RUN echo $(ls /tmp)
 ---> Running in aa1f900032f9
install-deps.sh
Removing intermediate container aa1f900032f9
 ---> eb455e78b7f6
Step 6/9 : RUN /tmp/install-deps.sh
 ---> Running in 6402a15cccb2
/bin/sh: /tmp/install-deps.sh: not found
ERROR: Service 'php' failed to build: The command '/bin/sh -c /tmp/install-deps.sh' returned a non-zero code: 127
```

The **install-deps.sh**:

```
#!/bin/sh

set -e

apk add --update --no-cache \
    postgresql-dev \
    mysql-client \
    yaml-dev \
    git \
    openssl

docker-php-ext-install pcntl pdo_mysql pdo_pgsql

# yaml
apk add --no-cache --virtual .build-deps g++ make autoconf
pecl channel-update pecl.php.net
pecl install yaml
docker-php-ext-enable yaml
apk del --purge .build-deps
```

Comment: Can you try `RUN sh /tmp/install-deps.sh `

Comment: Is the script file executable?  Why `echo $(...)` instead of just running the command directly?  (`RUN ls -l /tmp/install-deps.sh` without the `echo` wrapper.)

Comment: Running it with the `sh` gave an `illegal option` error.  Yes, it is executable, and I use the echo because I tried just an ls and I wasn't seeing the results when I ran `docker-compose build --no-cache`

Comment: We'd need to know more about that "illegal option" error. If the illegal option is a carriage return, f/e, that implies that you need to run dos2unix on the script.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Docker is executing the `install-deps.sh` script. The issue is with a command inside `install-deps.sh` that is not recognized when docker attempts to run the script.

As you can see the script returns an [error code of 127](https://linuxconfig.org/how-to-fix-bash-127-error-return-code) meaning that a command within the file does not exist.

For instance - try this:

```
touch test.sh
echo "not-a-command" >> test.sh
chmod 755 test.sh
/bin/sh -c "./test.sh"
```

Output:

```
/root/test.sh: line 1: not-a-command: command not found
```

Now check the exit code:

```
echo $?
127
```

I would suggest running the script inside an interactive environment to identify/install the command that is not found.

Comment: Yeah, you are right, if I make the file blank it works.  I think it has something to do with the `#!/bin/sh`.  I should be able to figure it out from here, when I find out what it is I'll comment on this question and then mark it as correct, thanks!

Comment: Is there any nice way of getting docker to spit out the output of the shell script it's trying to execute to make debugging a little easier?

Answer (score 0):

I was building an Alpine Linux image which had a bash script called in the Dockerfile that was failing with the dreaded "127" error.

## Short Answer:

Using the troubleshooting procedure later described, I discovered that there were actually (2) faults causing the 127 error:

**Fault 1 Fix**: Missing Package: In the Dockerfile I hadn't included `bash` with the other Alpine packages.

```
RUN apk add --no-cache --update bash app1 app2
```

**Fault 2 Fix**: `docker buildx build` command had a syntax error. I had added a bunch of tags and my local context (the "dot") ended up between them. I moved it to the end of the `build` command and with the other fix, all was happy:

```
time docker buildx build --no-cache --platform linux/arm64 \
-t f1linux/testrepo:test1 -t f1linux/testrepo:test2 -t \ 
f1linux/testrepo:test3 -f Dockerfile.COPY . --progress=plain
```

The 127 error feedback had me chasing a solution for the part of the Dockerfile calling the script when the error was actually consequential from a missing package and a syntax error in the `build` command.

Below follows how I isolated this compound fault

## Troubleshooting Procedure:

Since the part of the Dockerfile calling the bash script was found to be CORRECT, showing changes to correct code only serves to confuse. As such, I won't cover this territory, but limit review to steps taken to isolate where the fault *really* lived.

### Exclude Line Endings Issues:

After making no progress clearing the error in the part of the Dockerfile which downloads & executes the script, I began investigating non-obvious potential causes: non-printing characters.

**Check Line Endings**: Compare file encodings & line endings of the script being called in your Dockerfile and failing with scripts known to execute correctly in other Dockerfiles:

```
file -k script-Not-WORKING.sh
file -k script-WORKING.sh
```

**Fix Line Ending Issues**: Compare output of `git status` before and after `git normalize` to see if anything changed. If anything has, commit those changes.

```
git status
git add --renormalize .
git status
```

In my case `renormalize` made no changes and thereby excluded issues with Line Endings as being causal.

### Reduce Complexity:

So I tried tweaks to how the script was called in the Dockerfile without success and neither could I see issues with encodings or line endings. I had to reduce complexity as much as possible.

**Dockerfile**: I copied & trimmed my Dockerfile down to the fewest lines and made (2) changes to the stripped-down version:

*Change 1*: I added a line which listed did an `ls` to validated it was both present and executable in `--progress=plain` feedback during the build

*Change 2*: I commented-out the name of the failing script and changed it to `testscript.sh`

```
FROM docker.io/alpine:latest
LABEL com.F1Linux.image.version="001.000.000"
RUN apk add --no-cache --update app1 app2

COPY --chmod=755 scripts-config /root/scripts-config/

RUN ls -al /root/scripts-config/

#RUN /root/scripts-config/realscript.sh
RUN /root/scripts-config/testscript.sh
```

**Script**: Next I created `testscript.sh` to prove in principle that a script could be executed successfully and this would help exclude any issues with the script itself (excluding the she-bang) being causal of the fault:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "Hello World"
```

After creating it I `chmod 777` the short test script

**NOTE**: `chmod 777` is dangerous and should never EVER be used on a live production system. After you're done testing delete this file.

**`Docker buildx build`**: I simplified this by removing `--build-arg` and `BUILDVAR=` parameters, as all but 1 tag:

```
time docker buildx build --no-cache --platform linux/arm64 \
-t f1linux/testrepo:test1 . -f Dockerfile.COPY --progress=plain
```

Remark the `--no-cache` as a parameter: this ensures we start with a clean slate each build.

### Execution:

Executing the simplified `docker buildx build` command still failed, but slightly differently this time. The local context "dot" was now no longer sandwhiched between tags, so the test script was failing with an `error 2`. Although an error, it wasn't the `127 error`, so progress was made by identifying the fault in the `build` command.

A bit of Googling and I found a Stack post about adding the `bash` package. I executed the simplified `build` command again with the additional package and the test script was now successfully executing.

Armed with the knowledge gained in my reduced complexity test environment, I was able to fix the failing Dockerfile and the `build` command.

## Conclusion:

Hope both the short answer and how I arrived at it helps others stuck. I also wanted to ensure I wrote this down in case I ever get into this kind of pain again...

Comment: `chmod 777` should be eliminated, permanently, from _everyone's_ debugging toolbox. Making anything both world-writable and executable concurrently is throwing away the UNIX permissions model absent very specific targeted mitigating circumstances; it means that _any_ compromise to the container or system, even to a completely unprivileged user, can reach into any account that touches the filesystem content with permissions so modified.

Comment: Hi @CharlesDuffy I just needed to ensure I could get it to work in principle- I definitely never do such a thing on a production system. The `chmod' was on the test script and it was immediately deleted after I figured out how things were breaking. Appreciate your feedback and I'll add your note to my answer. Thanks!