# How to gain visibility of the output of a bash script executed from a Dockerfile?

Tags: docker, dockerfile, docker-run

I received this [error message](https://stackoverflow.com/q/62390765/5783745) which means something is [erroring inside a bash script executed by the Dockerfile](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62391785/5783745).

As an example, if something inside test.sh errors:

```
RUN test.sh
# 16 ERROR: executor failed running [/bin/sh -c test.sh]: exit code: 127
```

#### Question

What is the recommended way to gain visibility over the exact error message (i.e. to find out what's gone wrong) and to diagnose which line(s) of a bash script executed from a Dockerfile are problematic? Can docker be made to provide the output of the bash script so the exact error message is provided? Rather than just the somewhat cryptic:

```bash
executor failed running  exit code: 127
```

as seen [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/62390765/5783745).

#### What I know so far

One way to diagnose which line(s) is playing up is to survey the script, assess which line(s) might be causing problems, and comment out the suspect line and everything after it. If the error goes away, you've found the (first) line that is a problem, and it can be addressed. Rinse and repeat until the script is error-free. But this seems more manual than one would hope.

Comment: build the image up to this build step, start a container, execute the script manually and investigate...

Comment: The shell `-x` option could potentially help here – add `set -x` inside your script, or explicitly run it with `RUN sh -x your_script.sh` – but "exit code: 127" sort of sounds like it's maybe a wrong-architecture image, or the script names an interpreter that's not present in your image (not all Docker images contain bash for example).  Just as you've shown it it's also possible that `test.sh` isn't in `$PATH` anywhere and you need to `RUN ./test.sh`.

Comment: Also if you want to have line numbers for debugging you can follow this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17805088/5625089)

Comment: @DavidMaze I found the error very quickly using `RUN sh -x your_script.sh`, thank you. You can make it an answer is you think it may help others.